# Install windows back from linux

Tags: linux, windows, installation, administrator

Recently, we bought a laptop where Windows was pre-installed. Later, we realized that we need Linux to work on and one employee installed Linux on that. I do not know how he did that, what partitions he modified etc.

Now, the intent is to bring Windows back on it. There are two possible solutions I can think of:

Repair what I have. Which is not difficult because I do not know what exactly I have.

Start afresh. Clean up Linux and partitions. Create new partitions and install windows on it.

Which approach do the champs suggest?

I am open to answer all possible queries on it. Thanks a lot in. advance.

Comment: The answer depends on what is left on your disk. Please add to your post the partitions map on the disk.

Comment: Make and model of PC???

Comment: @harrymc. Hi Harry, thanks for your reply. Please let me know the information you want to know. If I understand you correctly, `diskpart` show me only 1 disk currently. Something like this:

Disk#        Status     Size       Free
Disk 0       Online     14GB     0B

If I try to create another partition with command `create partition primary size=8000`, it tells me that 'No usable free context could be found ...'

Comment: @HemantBhargava Open Gparted and upload a screenshot of what you see. You can download gparted by `sudo apt install gparted`

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have erased Windows and installed instead
Linux, but would like to reverse the process and return to Windows.

It's unlikely that you have left anything to repair for returning
to Windows, and it's not recommended to to whatever leftovers of
Windows that still exist.

I would recommend instead to start from a fresh installation of Windows.
If you had previously had Windows 10 installed on the computer,
the Microsoft licensing servers would still have recorded the
digital entitlement of your computer, so that Windows activation will
be automatic.

So what I suggest:

- Leave Linux in place and use it to create a Bootable Window 10 media.
  There are many methods for doing so, so here are a few.
  Use the one that suits best your Linux, paying attention to the variants
  that pertain to UEFI or BIOS, or to 64-bit (your recent computer
  is certainly not 32-bit):

  - [How to Create a Bootable Windows 10 USB in Linux](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/)
  - [How to Easily Create Windows 10 Bootable USB on Ubuntu or Any Linux Distro](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/easily-create-windows-10-bootable-usb-ubuntu)
  - [How to Create a Bootable Windows 10 USB on Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/create-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu)
- Boot the Windows media and delete all the existing partitions,
  leaving it all as one Unallocated space.
- Let Windows install itself to the disk and allocate all the
  required partitions.
  If asked to enter a serial number, skip this step.
- When the installation is done, remove the boot media and boot normally.

Answer (score -4):

I would have to know how you installed Linux.  Usually when people install Linux on a PC with Windows they would partition so that both are installed but it is also possible to completely format the drive.  If you have done the former so it is dual boot then check during startup if there is an option to choose if you want to start Windows or Linux.  It might only show a short time so stay alert.  If you have done the latter then I'm afraid it is not looking good and you might have to do a complete reinstall of Windows and possibly of Linux as the installation of Windows might stop it from running.  I haven't done it in several years but before you would need a product key but I fear you might need to purchase a new version, but I am not 100% sure of this.  It was the case though that if you use assisted technology, e.g. screen magnifiers, sticky keys etc. you can get Windows 10 for free.